# How to associate custom ports in GCP load balancer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create a Tcp Load Balancer in GCP and my need is to associate two custom ports with it. Let it be 80 and 86. Example

`ipconfig    Regional (us-east1) 34.138.170.126:80-86`    
`

But the GCP is taking it as a range, rather than having two distinguished ports. I am trying to find a way to achieve this. I tried to create two separate Forwarding rule names but it comes out with two ips which I do not want.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try giving a comma between the ports instead of giving it as a range. I am able to create a TCP load balancer through the console using a comma.

Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/setting-up-tcp) for the information on TCP proxy load balancer setup.
Also, refer to the [port specifications for forwarding rules](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts#port_specifications) and this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/909517/google-cloud-load-balancing-with-custom-port) has additional information in the answers

Comment: I tried to do this way----> 80,86.     But I am getting following error     ----->.   
Port/range not valid: must be a single port number or two port numbers separated by a dash